# Splitting a group of people into two groups

Tags: combinatorics

I have four people and I want to split them into two groups, one with one person, and the other one with three people. There are four ways to do this.

However, if I want two groups, each with two people, there are 3 ways to do so - I first choose one person, and then I have three other choices, so $ 1 \cdot 3 = 3 $.

Why aren't there six ways?

There are four options for the first person, three choices for the second,, so  overall there are $ \frac{4\cdot3}{2} = 6 $ ways.

Comment: Because the groups aren't labeled.  The assignment $(AB), (CD)$ is the same as $(CD), (AB)$.  If you labeled the two groups, then there would be $6$.

Comment: But choosing $1,2$ then $3,4$ is the same as choosing $3,4$ then $1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the four people be James, Charlie, Bodo and Wick. All the possible two teams of two are
[James, Charlie],[Bodo, Wick]
[James, Bodo],[Charlie, Wick]
[James, Wick], [Bodo, Charlie]
If you were considering one team of two individually, then there would be six possibilities($4\choose2$)

But since we are considering the two teams together, the members that were in the first team are just in the second team, so we would count them twice and hence get six. To avoid this, we get half of six, i.e., 3.